# SSH: вход в директорию (cd)

Tags: c#, ssh, клиент-сервер

Создал на форме кнопку (button) и при нажатии, хочу чтобы отсылалась команда на удаленный сервер (запуск игрового сервера), но не получается, хотя через [putty](http://www.putty.org/) всё работает прекрасно.

Вот код:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo("ip", port, "user", "password");
    using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                client.RunCommand("cd srv-cr-mp-c3-linux");
                client.RunCommand("nohup ./samp03svr-cr &");
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Ошибка";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            label1.Text = "Ошибка";
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Подключение проходит успешно, но не работает команда **входа в директорию**, а за ней, соответственно, и вторая команда. Потому что вторая команда должна выполняться в папке **srv-cr-mp-c3-linux**. Пробовал делать вход в другую (созданную) папку, но всё равно не работает. Права ставил *777*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А полный путь к папке указывать не пробовали?

Comment: Если что, при логине через `ssh username@host` вы попадаете в папку `/home/username`.

Comment: Кстати, неплохо бы рассказать, как именно не работает ваш код. Ошибка? Приложите стектрейс.

Comment: Спасибо ребят, я разобрался.

Comment: раскройте тайну, в чем проблема-то была и как решили? Лучше в виде ответа. Вы можете принять собственный ответ. А то вопрос так и повис без ответа. Может кому-то пригодится позже.

Answer (score 2):

Эти методы выполняются из рабочей директории:

```
// ...
{
    client.RunCommand("cd srv-cr-mp-c3-linux");
    client.RunCommand("nohup ./samp03svr-cr &");
}
// ...
```

Каждый раз, когда вызываешь `RunCommand()`. Тебе нужно для `client` указать `workingDir`, либо выполнить 
`cd srv-cr-mp-c3-linux | nohup ./samp03svr-cr &`,
тогда сначала ты переходишь в директорию, а там выполняешь что тебе нужно.

Линукса под рукой нет, могу ошибиться, еще попробуй 
`cd srv-cr-mp-c3-linux && nohup ./samp03svr-cr &` - это по очереди выполнит команды.

Answer (score 0):

Забыл отписаться, но лучше поздно, чем никогда.

```
client.RunCommand("cd srv-cr-mp-c3-linux; nohup ./samp03svr-cr &");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, это дополнение к вопросу или ответ?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ответ.